# How would I repeat a function repeat only when an if statement is true [PY]

Tags: python, discord.py

So basically I'm trying to generate different caseIDs, but to avoid duplicates I'm trying to re-run the function if the case is already in the database.

Here's some code:

```py
async def openuseless():
    with open("caseids.json", "r") as f:
        caseids = json.load(f)
    return caseids

async def addcaseidtodb(caseid):
    e = openuseless()
    
    e[str(caseid)] = {}

    with open("caseids.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(e, f)
    return True

async def id_generator(size=10, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    x = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
    existing = openuseless()

    for caseid in existing:
        if caseid == x:
            # repeat function
            print("e")
        else: 
            await addcaseidtodb(x)
```

The questions is: How would I repeat the function from if caseid == x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general pattern for this is

```py
def some_function():
    while True:
        # do things
        if not repeat_condition:
            break  # or return or etc
```

You'll see this a lot for input validation.

```py
def get_integer(prompt="Enter an integer: "):
    while True:
        user_input = input(prompt)
        try:
            result = int(user_input)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input -- must be an integer")
        return result
```